# Android : How to get unique Sequence Number for every response on every request sent

Tags: android, http, sequence, httpresponse

I am creating the app i.e instant messaging android app on version 4.0.3. I have to create a sequence number for every response I get from the server, so that I cant repeat the message which I get from the server/client. 
I have done google & visited many sites but dint get proper way or an idea to solve it.

If any idea or help will appreciated.

Many Thanks..

Comment: you need random number or unique number? for Unique number you can use `System.currentTimeMillis();` :)

Comment: why not use a generate a random number on the serverlike a GUID to make sure everything is unique.  If you also want to make sure messages are sequenced correctly also pass the server time in milliseconds?

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem -- I shouldn't want to print same message which I get from server. for example : If I send "Hi", I ll get response from another person "HELLO". Don't want to print hello many times by server, Want to restrict that. How I can do using System.currentTimeMillis().. ?????

Comment: @JonAlb -- I ll try random number & let you know. But if I can done in sequence , the duplicate messages can be restricted.

Comment: Using a single incrementing sequence creates a single locking hotspot, and will reduce your ability to scale this across multiple servers.